# Mysql select query with large result doesn't return any result

Tags: mysql, select, large-files

I am running a mysql select query as below

```
mysql -h <host> -u user -p -e "select * from db.table" > /tmp/1.txt
```

When the expected output size is greater than 2GB, it doesn't return any result. The output text file is empty.
Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to get around this?

Background: MySql is running on AWS RDS and I cannot use OUTFILE to redirect to file.

Comment: What distro/version of mysql are you using?

Comment: Sounds like your `mysql` is compiled in 32-bit mode, so it can't access large files.

Comment: Mysql client version : 5.6.31
Mysql server is running on AWS RDS : MySQL 5.6.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I have used to limit to create smaller files and merged them.

```
mysql -h <host> -u user -p -e "select * from db.table limit 0, 100000 " > /tmp/1.txt
mysql -h <host> -u user -p -e "select * from db.table limit 100000, 100000 " >> /tmp/1.txt
```